# RadioButtonList messed up in IE

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a RadioButtonList:

```
<p>
    <label for="rblIAm">I am</label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblIAm" ValidationGroup="RegForm" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Gay" Value="Gay"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Bisexual" Value="Bisexual"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Straight" Value="Straight"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</p>
```

With CSS like so:

```
label {
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
    font-size: 90.9%;
    padding-left: 1em;
}

input {
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 90.9%;
    height: 20px;
    clear: right;
}

input[type=radio] {
    height: 11px;
    border: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

In Chrome it looks fine:

[image: Chrome]

In IE it looks messed up:

[image]

Can someone explain what's going wrong and the fix?

Thanks

Comment: My first thought is, it looks like IE is rendering the radio buttons as a block element instead of inline an element, can you provide the resulting html?

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: What is the generated HTML code? That's what matters in rendering.
The markup is odd in several ways - there's `<label>` where `<legend>` or a heading would be appropriate, and radio buttons conventionally precede their labels (you can deviate from this if you like but it reduces usability and causes rendering problems). If you want to set things up in a tabular manner, then `<table>` would be the right tool, not floating. Floating often prevents things from lining up (even the Chrome rendering is less than optimal, the lines are not, er, straight).

Comment: Interested in your comments Jukka, as this form HTML & CSS comes from CSS Mastery, almost verbatim. The Chrome line is straight to the box that surrounds the radio button, the box is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, stripped it back and re-created with clearer (I hope) classes, which now work fine in all browsers. CSS:

```
fieldset
```

{
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    background: #000;
}

legend
{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

label.label
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
}

textarea
{
    width: 157px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 90.9%;
    font-family: Arial;
}

select.birthday
{
    width: 52px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 90.9%; 
}

select.ddl
{
    width: 162px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 90.9%;
}

input[type="text"]
{
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 90.9%;
}

.right-input
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}

Form:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEnquiryForm" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="no-display">Hello</legend>
                    <p>
                        <label class="label" for="txtFirstName">Name</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" ValidationGroup="RegForm" MaxLength="25" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" Text="*" CssClass="validation-error"
                            Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="RegForm" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label class="label" for="txtLastName">Name</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" ValidationGroup="RegForm" MaxLength="25" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLastName" ControlToValidate="txtLastName" Text="*" CssClass="validation-error"
                            Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="RegForm" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label class="label" for="txtEmail">Email</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="RegForm" MaxLength="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Text="*" CssClass="validation-error"
                            Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="RegForm" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Text="*" CssClass="validation-error"
                             Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$"
                             ValidationGroup="RegForm" runat="server"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label class="label" for="txtPostcode">Postcode</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostcode" ValidationGroup="RegForm" MaxLength="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPostcode" ControlToValidate="txtPostcode" Text="*" CssClass="validation-error"
                            Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="RegForm" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label class="label" for="txtBirthday">Birthday</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDay" ValidationGroup="RegForm" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="birthday" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" ValidationGroup="RegForm" CssClass="birthday" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" ValidationGroup="RegForm" CssClass="birthday" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label class="label" for="gender">Gender</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Gender" CssClass="ddl" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="-- select --" Value="Did not say"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="Male"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="Female"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label class="label" for="iam">I am</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Iam" CssClass="ddl" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="-- select --" Value="Did not say"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Straight" Value="Straight"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Gay Male" Value="Gay Male"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Lesbian" Value="Lesbian"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Trans Gender" Value="Trans Gender"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Bisexual" Value="Bisexual"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Queer" Value="Queer"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Do not want to disclose" Value="Do not want to disclose"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label class="label" for="txtMobile">Mobile</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" ValidationGroup="RegForm" MaxLength="12" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label class="label" for="txtEnquiry">Enquiry</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnquiry" ValidationGroup="RegForm" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Columns="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </p>

                    <p class="right-input">
                        I agree to the <a id="termsandconditions" href="Terms.htm">terms &amp; conditions</a>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAgreeTerms" ValidationGroup="RegForm" CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="right-input">
                        Receive the latest offers by email<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAgreeEmail" Checked="true" CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" />
                    </p>
                    <p class="right-input">
                        Receive the latest offers by SMS<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAgreeSMS" Checked="true" CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="right-input">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imbSubmit" ImageUrl="~/images/forms/submit-button.png" ValidationGroup="RegForm"
                             OnClick="imbSubmit_Click" CssClass="submit" runat="server" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imbSkip" ImageUrl="~/images/forms/skip-button.png" OnClick="imbSkip_Click"
                             CssClass="submit" runat="server" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks to all that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try css for input and label "display:inline-block"

Answer (score 0):

I've got to be honest I lost my rag with it and changed it to a drop down list. Utterly cheese me off that IE/Chrome/FF/Safari/Opera can't sort their acts out.